# Copy dataframe from one Excel file to a different Excel file

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to use openpyxl to open an Excel file, create a dataframe from filtered data in one of the sheets, and then write that data to an existing sheet in another file, but I keep getting an error saying that the permission is denied, I think because the way I'm calling the dataframe in the append step is somehow opening the file again after I've closed it or something.  So I guess I'm wondering if there's a way to somehow get the dataframe of source data into Python, and then close out that source file, open the destination file, and write the dataframe to it.  I apologize if that doesn't make sense; I'm pretty new to Python.

My code is below, and any suggestions or simplifications are welcome.

```
# Get latest source report using list
list_of_files_source = glob.glob(r'C:[my_path]/*')
latest_file_source = max(sorted(list_of_files_source, key = os.path.getctime))

# Load "Employee OT Data" sheet from workbook
file_source = pd.ExcelFile(latest_file_source)
df_source_Employee_OT = pd.read_excel(latest_file_source, 'Employee OT Data')

# Identify 6 most recent weeks (based on week ending date)
wk_end_source = pd.DataFrame(df_source_Employee_OT, columns = ['WEEK_ENDING']).drop_duplicates().apply(pd.to_datetime)
recent_wk_end_source = wk_end_source.sort_values(['WEEK_ENDING'], ascending=False).groupby('WEEK_ENDING').head(1)
recent_wk_end_source = recent_wk_end_source.head(6)
print(recent_wk_end_source)

# Filter source employee data for only 6 most recent weeks
df_source_Employee_OT = recent_wk_end_source.merge(df_source_Employee_OT, on='WEEK_ENDING', how='inner')
file_source.close()

# Make sure Excel instances are closed
import os
os.system("taskkill /f /im  EXCEL.exe")

# Load destination workbook, targeting 'SOURCEDATA' sheet
dst = r'C:[my_other_path/Pivots.xlsm')
pivots = xw.Book(str(r'C:[my_other_path]/Pivots.xlsm'))
pivots_source_sheet = pivots.sheets['SOURCEDATA']

# Clear out old data from sheet
pivots_source_sheet.range('2:100000').api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp)

# Save report and close
pivots.save(dst)

# Append with source data
with pd.ExcelWriter(dst, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    df_source_Employee_OT.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=pivots_source_sheet, startrow = 2)

pivots.save(dst)
pivots.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This part should not be needed since the excel app is never opened, python just reads the data from an excel file, not from the software itself.

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /f /im  EXCEL.exe")
```

You can pass the name of the excel file directly to `pandas.read_excel` and `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`.

Check out the official documentation for [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel). The first one returns a dataframe given the name of an excel file, while the second is called on a dataframe and saves it to an excel file given the target file name. That should be all you need for file i/o. If these functions do not work for some reason, please include the error message you are getting.